# iOS huge memory consumption when show image

Tags: ios, image, png

My application receiving a response from a server. The response contains png representation of some image in its body. The size is few kilobytes. I create an image object with

```
UIImage(data: response.data)
```

The image is shown by

```
imageView.image = image
```

Right after it, the application consumes around 100Mb more. It does not reproduce on the simulator. How is it possible? How could I fix the issue?

Comment: use xcode instruments to check where all that memory is allocated

Comment: PNG files are compressed. When you use them, they are uncompressed and can take far more memory (e.g. often 4 bytes per pixel). E.g. a 5000 x 5000 pixel image will take 100mb, regardless of the size of the file or the size of the image view on which you're trying to use it. What are the pixel dimensions of the image you're trying to use? (Note, not file size; not size of image view, but rather the dimensions of the image in the file.) You might want to resize it to something commensurate with the image view in question.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. It looks like an iOS bug. The image has size 1920*1080 it should take 8Mb. I got another suggestion to store the image as a file and then load it again. It seems weird, but I'll try and write here if it works.

Comment: Does not work. The consumption is still around 100Mb per image.

Comment: Well, if you want help, we'll need a [simple, reproducible example of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Investigated closer. The problem is on the server. It returns 8000*4500 image instead of 1920*1080 for some reason. Thanks for attention, the issue is fixed.